# Simple MathJax not displaying in IE

Tags: mathjax

I have a short MathJax page that displays great in Chrome (63.0.3239.132) and Firefox (57.0.4), but it fails to render in IE (11.0.9600.18893).  As you can see, I'm using MathJax 2.7.2, which appears to be the latest release.  I can correctly see https://www.mathjax.org/, so it's not a generic rendering problem.

Any thoughts as to what might be going on?

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testing MathJax</title>
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
Test formula: $y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML document above works fine for me in IE11 on Windows 7.  Do you have any extensions that might be interfering with javascript?  Are there any errors in the browser's console log?  (Reload the page when the log is open to be sure to get any messages that occur during page load.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I was restricting "this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls".  I didn't investigate what different mechanism mathjax.net was using to display correctly.  Regardless, once I clicked "allow" in IE, it loaded fine.